# Android App re-opens upon "back-out"

Tags: android, android-activity, back

On my application when I back out of the menu screen to leave the application it re-opens and displays one of the Views that are further into the app than the main menu.  On my debugger it says simply

```
    06-08 11:00:53.952: INFO/ActivityManager(120): Displayed activity com.app/mainmenu: 1653 ms (total 1653 ms)

//I press back to leave the app back to the main screen

    06-08 11:00:58.112: INFO/ActivityManager(120): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.app/gridview (has extras) }
```

No explaination as to why it is opening that screen.

I have placed this Method (possibly the wrong technical term) in both of the activities that are involved.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Any ideas as to why it might be doing this?  I have considered inserting some sort of "kill-app" code but I have read that it's ill-advised.

update;  thanks for the suggestion inazaruk, I removed the onBackPressed() override on both screens and it does the same thing.

If I am using the wrong terms when searching for a way to solve this, someone please advise.  I do like solving things on my own.  When I use the keywords (the tags that are linked to this article) I get alot of message boards for users and not a lot of development boards.  (I throw in the word Java and developer sometimes, but they yield results far from what I am looking for)

update 2:  looks like I should take a look at something referenced here
[How can I programmatically close an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099439/how-to-close-an-application-programaticaly)
my gridview may be doing some things wrong.

Another update:

```
<activity android:name=".Menu" android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".mImageGridview"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.hagsvision.mImageGridview" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

possible that "default"?

I should try that on a lady "hey baby.  Show me your manifest"

Solved it, on the main menu I was incorrectly implementing an onTouchListener.  When I press the back button it apparently qualifies as an "onTouch" and it went to a default selection.  I changed it to implement a onClick listener and it functions properly now.

I also removed the category.DEFAULT from the manifest though I don't think that it was the problem.

Comment: It looks like `onBackPressed` has nothing to do with what you see. Try removing it and see if you can still reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Show us your manifest, it could be possible gridview is listening to some intent which it should not be listening to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, on the main menu I was incorrectly implementing an onTouchListener. When I press the back button it apparently qualifies as an "onTouch" and it went to a default selection. I changed it to implement a onClick listener and it functions properly now.

Comment: I think I have to wait 24 hours.  But thanks bjarkjef.  It definitely more awesome to discover your own problem.