# Android: Detect when soft keyboard gets enabled

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have started the ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTING intent which give user the possiblity to activate a softInput (keyboard). I want to close the setting activity(the intent I started) when user activated my desired soft input/keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14065738) from [Sujay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746680/sujay):

You can close all activities from background and when re-open the app It starts from first activity

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CloseApp.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can close all activities from background and when re-open the app It starts from paused activity[where you closed] activity

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to determine it - see http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/1728f26f2334c060/5e4910f0d9eb898a where Dianne Hackborn from the Android team has replied. However, you can detect it indirectly by checking if the window size changed in #onMeasure. See Android: [Is software keyboard shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   InputMethodManager imm  = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   Log.e(TAG, "Result :"+imm.isActive());
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried isActive() before. The output from the log is "false" even when the keyboard is working fine, that i do not understand.

Comment: By InputMethodManager I can only show the InputMerhodSelection. I can't make it enabled.